# How get params to Zend Framework 2 Soap

Tags: php, soap, zend-framework2

```
    //class generator
    class SoapActions
    {
        /**
        * Return simple test
        *
        * @param Array $params
        * @return Array
        */

        public function getParams($params)
        {
            return $params;
        }
    }

    //wsdl code
    $autodiscover = new AutoDiscover();
    $autodiscover->setClass('SoapActions');
    $autodiscover->setUri('/params');
    $autodiscover->handle();

    //server code
    $server = new Server('/wsdl');
    $server->setClass('SoapActions');
    $server->setObject(new SoapActions());
    $server->handle();

    //client
    $client = new Client('/wsdl');
    $result = $client->getParams(array('opt' => 'test'));
    return $result;
```

In $result nothing...

Comment: I think the problem is the Array, if I am not mistaken soap won't have array, why don't you try to do it with a string? For array you should create complex types. So For example @param \Application\Soap\MyArrayClass $params

Comment: add ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", 0); in //server code

Comment: on development only, on production it will make it a bit slower.